# What happens to child theme if I change to new version of parent theme?

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, parent-theme

What happens to child theme if I change to new version of parent theme? Tesseract theme came out with new version. But what happens to all changes saved in original Tesseract child theme? Will changes made in Child theme work with new version? Instructions say to remove old theme before uploading new Tesseract theme so I can't go back if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be super safe, you can do this method:

- I would recommend first connecting to the theme folder via FTP. If
  you haven't made any templates or custom php pages etc, you can
  rename the theme folder _backup at the end.
- Then just drag in the new theme in the same theme folder location.
- Simply go to your dashboard and activate the new theme.
- Then activate the child theme again and see if there are any issues.

If the new theme messes up your child theme, you can try to resolve the issues, or revert back to the old version by deleting the new theme, removing the _backup on the old theme folder and reactivating everything.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

All settings are stored under child theme domain, so no worries. Just make sure you maintain the same parent theme folder name after updates. You could always backup the old one by renaming its folder.

Comment: Thanks Zlatev. I started rebuilding a website using WP with Tesseract theme last August. Evidently along the way I copied the entire header.php ad style.css files to my child theme and have made changes to these as I went along, instead of just putting the changes into a file on the child theme, which I think I should have done. So, will this make a difference when changing to the updated Tesseract theme?

Answer (score 0):

What happens depends on the changes made to the parent theme. The developers should of course make certain that their new version is backwards compatible, so your child theme still works with the updated parent. However, this is not necessarily so. Therefore, you should test the updated parent with your child theme before you apply it to a live site.